# Quadratic $y = -4.9x^2 + 25x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Here is my questions, please help.

In the game of foot, a team can score by kicking the ball over a bar and between two uprights. For a kick in a particular game, the height of the ball above the ground, $y$, in meters, can be modeled by the function

$$Y = -4.9x^2 + 25x$$

Where $x$ is the time in seconds after the ball left the foot of the player.
A) Determine the maximum height that this kick reached to the nearest tenth of a meter. 
B) how long was the ball in the air?

Thanks!

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: try writing the equation in vertex form

Answer (score 0):

$h=(25-4.9t)t$. By symmetry, it takes as long to ascend than to descend, i.e. the half of $25/4.9$ s, and the height reached is $25/2\cdot25/9.8$ m.